TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createDocumentFragment')
So, I found that this error usually comes up when you're using AJAX. The problem is: I don't. I tried to use $(this.element) instead, but then it returnes only undefined.
So, my code is (I reduced it to bare minimum for you to understand):
$("document").ready(() => {  
    $(".department-item").on("click", () => {
        console.log($(this).text())
    })
})


That's what I get from that:


What environment are you attempting to use for that code? In a browser I don't think it would do anything unless the page has a <document> element. (The jQuery call should be just $(document).ready(...)

Oh also, don't use => functions for jQuery event handlers if you want access to this in the functions.

@Pointy I just look at it in the browser right away. But yes, the problem was with arrow functions, I did wonder if they would screw me. Thanks for help!
